# Wear-OS Tiles and marquee_forever

Tags: textview, wear-os, wear-os-tiles

How would one go about adding the attributes like the below to a text component in a Wear-OS Tile

```
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:singleLine="true"
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not supported, you should file an FR.

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=1112273&template=1623657

Comment: I am not a Google emp, so not sure if I can use the above link to file an FR :)

Comment: Good point, fixed.